# Move project from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code

I have created a project on OSX in Visual Studio Code (MVC Website template using yeoman) and added to source control (Git), however when I try to work on the project in Windows using Visual Studio 2015 I am unable to open the project as it has no solution file.

I assume that creating an entirely new project on Visual Studio 2015 and then copy pasting my project on top might work but if there is a better solution I would love to know!

Perhaps there is a way to make the solution file on the mac so it can be 'cross platform' instead of 'multi platform' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no scaffolder for sln files.

You have to create a sln file by hand or by using Visual Studio.

Comment: This is a good thing to remember. If starting a new project, probably best to create the solution from Visual Studio first. This way when pulling code from source control when working cross-platform, everything will "just" work.

Comment: Adding a sln file is not a problem after the project is created. Just create an empty solution in VS and then add your projects to it. VS can create the xproj files from project.json

Comment: Does VSCode use xproj to load the the project files or just read everything off a directory? How well will it work with multiple projects?

Comment: VS code loads everything in a given folder, unless you explicitly exclude something. It uses project.json to identify dnx projects and it has no notion of xproj